# How to pass queues between ExecutorsServices that are in different classes?

Tags: java, threadpoolexecutor, blockingqueue

I have created two patterns: one which starts `class X` (which contains thread started with `ExecutorService`, name it Es), second one starts `class Y` (which also contains thread started with `ES`). Now, both of them are started inside `class Z` with `Es`. However, `Z` also starts group of threads (`ES` again) directly from itself.

```
public class Z { 
...
public static void main(String [] args)
    { 
    service=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(xNum);
        for(int k=0; k < xNum; k++){
            X x=new X(k);
            service.submit(x);
        }

    service=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(yNum);
        for(int k=0; k < yNum; k++){
            Y y=new Y(k);
            service.submit(y);
        }

    service=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(zNum);
        for(int k=0; k < zNum; k++){
            directThread dt=new directThread(queue1, queue2, queue3);
            service.submit(dt);

        }
    }
}
```

Inside class X there are many threads, but one interests me particularly":

```
public class X{
    ...
     public void run(){
        while(true){
          ...
        service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(XStuffNum);
        for (int i=0; i < SStuffNum; i++) {
            service.submit(new FirstClass(blocking1, blocking2, blocking3));
        }
        }
     }
}
```

cognately in `Y` class there is `SecondClass`. 
queue and blocking are names for BlockingQueues.

So `dt` is supposed to take data from `FirstClass` blocking, put them inside its queues, and then pass them to `SecondClass` queues. My question is, how to let `dt` take queues that are inside `FirsClass`?

EDIT. Problem solved. It is enough to create getters inside `X` and `Z` so `Y` can do `X.getQueue().operation()`

Comment: This is quite hard to follow with so many nondescript names.  If you need something from each X instance, why not keep those instances in a separate Collection?

Comment: Well, my main problem is that `Z`, `X`, `Y` generally share the same function: they starts threads. So depict it: `X` is Company that has class `Boss`, `CompanyWorker` etc, 'Y` for `Consumer`, `ShopWorker`. `Z` starts `X`, `Y` but also starts class `Transport`. So the `Transport` is supposed to take things from `CompanyWorker` queue put it to transportsQueue, and then give it to `ShopWorker` queue. So passing this queues is problematic.

Comment: Create the queues in `Z` and pass them to the appropriate constructors...

Comment: But `X` ->Company is created multiple times, so each one has an id. So every time new queue should be created. So how will we take data from queue with specific id?

Comment: Think about where the Queues need to go. Is there one `Transport` per `Company` ? -> Give the Queue for id a to Company and Transport with id a. Do all the messages go to one `Transport`? -> put all the messages into one Queue and put the id into the message. We need more real life information to help you. Also please edit additional info into the question!